# Spring-Apache Kafka-Update

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I have to make a dashboard that shows the information about a voting system. It is mandatory that I use spring and apache kafka technologies to make the applicatoin.

The objective of the dashboard is to show the modificationes in the voting system in real time. I already find out how to send and receive topics from kafka and I am able to show them in the web page but not dinamically, I have to reload the page. Does someone know what can I do in order to update the information in the web page when a new message from de kafka producer is received?.

Comment: How about Spring websockets?  Your web app could subscribe to a topic. When you receive a message via Kafka publish it to the topic the web app is subscribed to. This is just an idea. (https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: @jmw5598 do yo know something about ssemiter?